# How to do an average of data for the past N weeks?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 fields, Week and Sales. I would like to get the average of sales of the past 5 Weeks. How can I do that using a calculated field. I will need to use the average to display an up and down arrow afterwards. I was able to display only the latest 5 weeks in a tabular form.

Any suggestions?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Do you need average in another column or there should be average as a whole in report without individual columns?

Comment: In another column